# Why isn't Sentry registering my ASP .NET Core API calls as Transactions?

Tags: asp.net-core, sentry

I have an ASP .NET Core project integrated with `Sentry`:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            webBuilder.UseSentry(options =>
            {
                options.Dsn = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENTRY_DSN");
                options.Debug = true;
            });
        });
}
```

I can see all exceptions being logged as Issues in Sentry. I cannot see however, any transactions logged, even if I make plenty of REST API calls.

According to [Sentry's documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/guides/aspnetcore/configuration/options/), this setup should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sentry's performance monitoring features are opt-in and need to be enabled separately.  In addition to calling `UseSentry` as you showed, you should also do the following to capture transactions:

- [Configure the sample rate](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/guides/aspnetcore/performance/) by setting the `TracesSampleRate` in either the call to `UseSentry` or in your `appsettings.json` file.  For example, `options.TracesSampleRate = 1.0` will send traces for 100% of your transactions.  This is fine for dev/test, but in production you will likely want to use a much lower rate such as `0.2` (20%).

  - Optionally, you can also set a `TracesSampler` function that can be used if you have more complex logic for deciding whether to sample or not.
- Configure [automatic instrumentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/guides/aspnetcore/performance/instrumentation/automatic-instrumentation/) by calling `UseSentryTracing` in the `Configure` section of your `Startup` class.  Add this *after* `UseRouting`, which should already be there.  This adds Sentry's tracing middleware to the ASP.NET Core pipeline to collect traces from each request and response.
- If desired, you can add [custom instrumentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/guides/aspnetcore/performance/instrumentation/custom-instrumentation/) around other parts of your code, by creating additional transactions and spans.

Also, just FYI, if you're planning on using the `SENTRY_DSN` environment variable, then you don't need to *also* set `options.Dsn` in code.  It will be picked up automatically.

Comment: Thanks, this did the work indeed! Marked as accepted answer. May I ask, why would I want to catch only 20% of my transactions in production? Doesn't it mean that I might miss some of the caveats?

Comment: You *could* trace 100% of transactions, but depending on volume that could get expensive, since Sentry's pricing model is based on the amount of data received.  Also, when it comes to performance monitoring, you're likely to draw the same conclusions about what parts of your app are performing slowly given a small sample of the data as you would a large sample.  More on this [in the Sentry docs](https://docs.sentry.io/product/sentry-basics/tracing/distributed-tracing/#data-sampling).

Comment: Also note that the performance [`TracesSampleRate`](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/configuration/options/#traces-sample-rate) is separate from errors [`SampleRate`](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/configuration/options/#sample-rate).  By default, 100% of errors are captured.

Comment: Excellent answer Matt, thanks! Regarding the pricing model, is there an option to put a cap/throttle on the captured transactions per a unit of time, in case of a DDoS attack for instance?

Comment: Yes.  There are lots of options and some built-in safeguards as well.  See [Pricing & Billing](https://docs.sentry.io/product/accounts/pricing/) and [Quota Management](https://docs.sentry.io/product/accounts/quotas/), as well as [this from the FAQ](https://help.sentry.io/account/billing/what-happens-when-i-run-out-of-event-capacity-and-a-grace-period-is-triggered/).